# Detect if button is keep pressed

Tags: .net, vb.net, button

I've a button in a winform, if I pressed it I call the

```
Sub DoSomtheing();
```

I want that the program continue to call that sub until the button is released. I tried with click event and also with `MouseDown`, but they fired only one time.

Which is the best way to to that?

Comment: You would probably start a `Timer` on `MouseDown` and stop it on `MouseUp`, then call your method from the `Tick` event handler. You would need to consider what happens if the user drags the mouse off the `Button` without releasing.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I only saw your comment when the page refreshed after posting my answer!

Answer (score 1):

The best approach might be to respond to both the mouse down and mouse up events rather than just the click or mouse down.

On mouse down kick off your process on a background thread or a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0). This is so that the UI remains responsive.

On mouse up terminate the background thread. This might not be immediate so you'll need to ensure that this is OK.

You could also respond to the mouse leave event and terminate the thread in that case as well - to simulate the user's finger slipping off the button.

Answer (score 1):

Using the timers is the best approach I think:
ss

```
Sub DoSomething()
    i = i + 1
    Label1.Text = Str(i)
End Sub
```

Then in a timer, we can call this method:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    DoSomething()
End Sub
```

We can enable or disable the timer using this button mouse up and mouse down functions:

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseUp
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

You can change the timer interval to change the speed.